# Ghostscript 9.07 : PDF/X-1a:2001 : PDF/X output intent is missing

Tags: ghostscript, pdfa

Could you please tell me how to embedded the PDF/X output intent. When I check with preflight I reported that PDF/X-1a:2001 : PDF/X output intent is missing in the PDF file.

Problem faced in the PDF file:

```
1) PDF/X-1a:2001 : PDF/X version is not PDF/X-1a:2001
2) PDF/X-1a:2001 : PDF/X output intent is missing
3) PDF/X-1a:2001 : Document trapped flag is Unknown
4) PDF/X-1a:2001 : Text object uses invalid characters (.notdef glyphs)
```

GS Command:

```
gs -dPDFX -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE \
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=GS_Test.pdf PDFA_def.ps Test.ps
```

**PDFA_def.ps :**

```
%!
% This is a sample prefix file for creating a PDF/A document.
% Feel free to modify entries marked with "Customize".

% This assumes an ICC profile to reside in the file (ISO Coated sb.icc),
% unless the user modifies the corresponding line below.

% Define entries in the document Info dictionary :

/ICCProfile (/usr/share/ghostscript/9.07/iccprofiles/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc)   % Customize.
def

[ /Title (Title)                  % Customize.
/DOCINFO pdfmark

% Define an ICC profile :

[/_objdef {icc_PDFA} /type /stream /OBJ pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} <</N systemdict /ProcessColorModel get /DeviceGray eq {1} {4} ifelse >> /PUT pdfmark
[{icc_PDFA} ICCProfile (r) file /PUT pdfmark

% Define the output intent dictionary :

[/_objdef {OutputIntent_PDFA} /type /dict /OBJ pdfmark
[{OutputIntent_PDFA} <<
/Type /OutputIntent             % Must be so (the standard requires).
/S /GTS_PDFA1                   % Must be so (the standard requires).
/DestOutputProfile {icc_PDFA}            % Must be so (see above).
/OutputConditionIdentifier (ISO Coated v2 300% (ECI))      % Customize

/PUT pdfmark
[{Catalog} <</OutputIntents [ {OutputIntent_PDFA} ]>> /PUT pdfmark
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `gs` command, you're specifying the PDF-A definition file `PDFA_def.ps`.  You need to specify the PDF-X definition file instead.

Detailed instructions for creating a PDF-X/3 document are available [here](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFX).

Comment: Thanks Devnull, I need to embedded PDF/X-1a:2001, but in the document it shows PDF/X-3:2002. How to handle this PDF/x-1a:2001 compatibility

Comment: See this [thread](http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2009-September/008571.html).

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript doesn't currently support production of PDF/X-1, only PDF/X-3, PDF/A-1 and PDF/A-2. It isn't currently possible to convert all the colour definitions into the required colour space for PDF/X-1.